# How was the Statute of Secrecy breached in 1749 and what measures were introduced to prevent a recurrence?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, during the History of Magic O.W.L., Question 5 asks that:

> How was the Statute of Secrecy breached in 1749 and what measures were introduced to prevent a recurrence?

Does any one have any idea what this was about? Just curious to know since Rowling doesn't mention it in any of the books I have read yet.

Comment: For legal reasons we're not allowed to tell you.

Answer (score 6):

## It's unclear.

The only event that I could find that was near 1749 is: Clause 73.

> “In 1750, Clause 73 was inserted in the International Code of Wizarding Secrecy, to which wizard ministries worldwide conform today:
>
> Each wizarding governing body will be responsible for the concealment, care, and control of all magical beasts, beings, and spirits dwelling within its territory’s borders. Should any such creature cause harm to, or draw the notice of, the Muggle community, that nation’s wizarding governing body will be subject to discipline by the International Confederation of Wizards.” 
> <sub><sup>*-
> Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (textbook)*</sup></sub>

So this might be what the ministry did to "stop the recurrance" of magical beasts harming Muggles.

Comment: there was [Bavarian nun executed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Renata_Saenger_von_Mossau) in 1749.

Answer (score 5):

If you read on a little, you'll learn that Harry thinks it might have something to do with **vampires.**

> He had a stab at question five (How was the Statute of Secrecy
>   breached in 1749 and what measures were introduced to prevent a
>   recurrence?) but had a nagging suspicion that he had missed several
>   important points; **he had a feeling vampires had come into the story
>   somewhere.**

Quite how/why vampires caused a breach isn't known. The [HP wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/1740s#cite_note-OP31-4) postulates that it may have been to do with the real world publishing of a treatise on the tracking and detection of vampires; Antoine Augustin Calmet's *[Dissertation on Vampires (1749)](https://maugis.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/dissertation-sur-les-vampires-dom-calmet-1749/)*

> *The breach in the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy in 1749
>   involving vampires may be inspired by the real-world work of
>   Benedictine monk Antoine Augustin Calmet, who is famous for being
>   among the first to record stories about vampires in Western Europe. In
>   1746, Calmet suggested that vampires may actually exist, and in 1749,
>   Calmet published a treatise that describes how to track them down in
>   their lairs and destroy them. If so, Calmet (or his source) may be a
>   wizard in the Harry Potter universe, since only wizards and witches
>   could possibly commit such a breach.*

Comment: Oh, then I guess a(or a group of) vampire must have broken the treatice and thus leading Calmet to find and kill him/her/it/them. And as @Niffler says, Clause 73 was introduced. Well interesting thinking that Rowling not only knew about this but also decided to mention it in rather a Easter egg way!!

Comment: @Sri - The info from the wiki is merely a guess, mark you.